# How to obtain results of an indexedDB cursor in reverse order

Tags: javascript, html, cursor, indexeddb

I've written the below code to iterate the rows of an object stored in an `indexedDB`. I'm using Google Chrome browser.

```
'use strict';
    var openRequest = indexedDB.open('Library', 1);
    var db;

    openRequest.onupgradeneeded = function(response)
    {
        console.debug(1);
        response.currentTarget.result.createObjectStore("authors",{ keypath: 'id', autoIncrement: true });
    }  

    openRequest.onsuccess = function(response) {
        console.debug('success opening indexeddb');
        db = openRequest.result;
       findAuthors();
    };

    function findAuthors() {
        var trans = db.transaction('authors', 'readonly');
        var authors = trans.objectStore("authors");
        var request = authors.openCursor();
        request.PREV = true;
        request.onsuccess = function(response) {
        var cursor = response.target.result;
        if (!cursor) {
        alert('No records found.');
        return;
        }
        alert('Id: ' + cursor.key + ' Last name: ' + cursor.value.lastName);
        cursor.continue();
        };
        request.onerror = function(response) { // display error
        };
    }
```

Records in my DB are as below:

[image]

Currently the iteration happens in order of keys 2,3 and then 4. What I want is that when I start iterating the cursor I get the rows with key 4, 3, and then 2 i.e. in reverse order. I tried using a `PREV` boolean attribute on the cursor object but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
request.PREV = true;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `authors.openCursor(null, 'prev');`

Also check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBObjectStore/openCursor for some documentation.

Comment: May want to fix that to be `authors.openCursor(null, 'prev')`

Comment: Whoops. Thanks for catching that!

Comment: ohh. Actually I had tried that route of passing the direction in second parameter. The book I'm referring from MS press talks about a constant `IDBCursor.PREV` (in their code sample) which can be passed as second argument but it didn't work. Then I tried the option which I've quoted in my post. I was not aware that it is actually a string constant (inside single or double quote) which is to be passed.

Comment: The indexedDB syntax went through some changes as it was being developed. There was a prior version of indexedDB where that syntax may have worked. But the current way is to use strings.